# Разметка Layout android

Tags: android, android-layout

Есть такая вот разметка,

Главный файл:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/l_like_group"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="21dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/bt_like_comment"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="4dp"
    android:paddingLeft="3dp"
    android:paddingTop="3dp"
    android:paddingBottom="3dp"
    android:background="@drawable/like_value_button_bg"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_like_type"
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:src="@drawable/i_default_like"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_comment_likes_count"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:text="10"
        tools:ignore="SpUsage" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**like_value_button_bg**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="#d8d8d8"/>
    <corners android:radius="3dp"/>
</shape>
```

**i_default_like.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="18dp"
    android:height="18dp"
    android:viewportWidth="18"
    android:viewportHeight="18">

<path
    android:fillColor="#EE0000"
    android:fillType="evenOdd"
    android:strokeWidth="1"
    android:pathData="M 3 0 L 15 0 Q 18 0 18 3 L 18 15 Q 18 18 15 18 L 3 18 Q 0 18 0 15 L 0 3 Q 0 0 3 0 Z" />
<path
    android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:fillType="evenOdd"
    android:strokeWidth="1"
    android:pathData="M7.17904941,6.00873908 C6.61983753,6.00873908            6.05793066,6.1835206
    5.63124709,6.60299625 C4.77791635,7.44194757 4.80133369,8.73533084
    5.63124709,9.57428215 L8.99999331,13 L12.3687395,9.57428215
    C13.1987258,8.73533084 13.2220339,7.44194757 12.3687395,6.60299625
    C11.5154452,5.79900125 10.1264292,5.79900125 9.2731349,6.60299625
    L8.99999331,6.88264669 L8.72685173,6.60299625        C8.30002248,6.1835206
    7.73826128,6.00873908 7.17904941,6.00873908 L7.17904941,6.00873908 Z" />
</vector>
```

**Второе изображение которое заменяется**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="30dp"
    android:height="35dp"
    android:viewportWidth="30"
    android:viewportHeight="35">

<path
    android:fillColor="#EE0000"
    android:fillType="evenOdd"
    android:strokeWidth="1"
    android:pathData="M 10 16 L 20 16 L 20 35 L 15 31 L 10 35 Z" />
<path
    android:fillColor="#000000"
    android:fillType="evenOdd"
    android:strokeWidth="1"
    android:pathData="M 15 27 L 12.653483 29.8153251 L 11.2917961 26.4126782 L 8.1901425 28.3650979 L 7.94657697 24.7082039 L 4.39339828 25.6066017 L 5.29179607 22.053423 L 1.63490214 21.8098575 L 3.5873218 18.7082039 L 0.184674891 17.346517 L 3 15 L 0.184674891 12.653483 L 3.5873218 11.2917961 L 1.63490214 8.1901425 L 5.29179607 7.94657697 L 4.39339828 4.39339828 L 7.94657697 5.29179607 L 8.1901425 1.63490214 L 11.2917961 3.5873218 L 12.653483 0.184674891 L 15 3 L 17.346517 0.184674891 L 18.7082039 3.5873218 L 21.8098575 1.63490214 L 22.053423 5.29179607 L 25.6066017 4.39339828 L 24.7082039 7.94657697 L 28.3650979 8.1901425 L 26.4126782 11.2917961 L 29.8153251 12.653483 L 27 15 L 29.8153251 17.346517 L 26.4126782 18.7082039 L 28.3650979 21.8098575 L 24.7082039 22.053423 L 25.6066017 25.6066017 L 22.053423 24.7082039 L 21.8098575 28.3650979 L 18.7082039 26.4126782 L 17.346517 29.8153251 Z" />
<path
    android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:fillType="evenOdd"
    android:strokeWidth="1"
    android:pathData="M 15 27 L 12.653483 29.8153251 L 11.2917961 26.4126782 L 8.1901425 28.3650979 L 7.94657697 24.7082039 L 4.39339828 25.6066017 L 5.29179607 22.053423 L 1.63490214 21.8098575 L 3.5873218 18.7082039 L 0.184674891 17.346517 L 3 15 L 0.184674891 12.653483 L 3.5873218 11.2917961 L 1.63490214 8.1901425 L 5.29179607 7.94657697 L 4.39339828 4.39339828 L 7.94657697 5.29179607 L 8.1901425 1.63490214 L 11.2917961 3.5873218 L 12.653483 0.184674891 L 15 3 L 17.346517 0.184674891 L 18.7082039 3.5873218 L 21.8098575 1.63490214 L 22.053423 5.29179607 L 25.6066017 4.39339828 L 24.7082039 7.94657697 L 28.3650979 8.1901425 L 26.4126782 11.2917961 L 29.8153251 12.653483 L 27 15 L 29.8153251 17.346517 L 26.4126782 18.7082039 L 28.3650979 21.8098575 L 24.7082039 22.053423 L 25.6066017 25.6066017 L 22.053423 24.7082039 L 21.8098575 28.3650979 L 18.7082039 26.4126782 L 17.346517 29.8153251 Z" />
<path
    android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:fillType="evenOdd"
    android:strokeWidth="1"
    android:pathData="M 15 27 L 12.653483 29.8153251 L 11.2917961 26.4126782 L 8.1901425 28.3650979 L 7.94657697 24.7082039 L 4.39339828 25.6066017 L 5.29179607 22.053423 L 1.63490214 21.8098575 L 3.5873218 18.7082039 L 0.184674891 17.346517 L 3 15 L 0.184674891 12.653483 L 3.5873218 11.2917961 L 1.63490214 8.1901425 L 5.29179607 7.94657697 L 4.39339828 4.39339828 L 7.94657697 5.29179607 L 8.1901425 1.63490214 L 11.2917961 3.5873218 L 12.653483 0.184674891 L 15 3 L 17.346517 0.184674891 L 18.7082039 3.5873218 L 21.8098575 1.63490214 L 22.053423 5.29179607 L 25.6066017 4.39339828 L 24.7082039 7.94657697 L 28.3650979 8.1901425 L 26.4126782 11.2917961 L 29.8153251 12.653483 L 27 15 L 29.8153251 17.346517 L 26.4126782 18.7082039 L 28.3650979 21.8098575 L 24.7082039 22.053423 L 25.6066017 25.6066017 L 22.053423 24.7082039 L 21.8098575 28.3650979 L 18.7082039 26.4126782 L 17.346517 29.8153251 Z" />
<path
    android:fillColor="#EE0000"
    android:fillType="evenOdd"
    android:strokeWidth="1"
    android:pathData="M 15 6 C 19.9705627485 6 24 10.0294372515 24 15 C 24 19.9705627485 19.9705627485 24 15 24 C 10.0294372515 24 6 19.9705627485 6 15 C 6 10.0294372515 10.0294372515 6 15 6 Z" />
<path
    android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:fillType="evenOdd"
    android:strokeWidth="1"
    android:pathData="M13.1790494,12.0087391 C12.6198375,12.0087391   12.0579307,12.1835206
    11.6312471,12.6029963 C10.7779164,13.4419476 10.8013337,14.7353308
    11.6312471,15.5742821 L14.9999933,19 L18.3687395,15.5742821
    C19.1987258,14.7353308 19.2220339,13.4419476 18.3687395,12.6029963
    C17.5154452,11.7990012 16.1264292,11.7990012 15.2731349,12.6029963
    L14.9999933,12.8826467 L14.7268517,12.6029963  C14.3000225,12.1835206
    13.7382613,12.0087391 13.1790494,12.0087391 L13.1790494,12.0087391 Z" />
</vector>
```

LinerLayout заполнен серым, слева изображение, справа TextView

Вопрос в следующем: Как можно про игнорировать границы LinerLayout? Т.е. есть изображения чуть больше стандартного и LinerLayout растягивается под изображение. А надо чтобы он(LinerLayout) остался того же размера, а изображение "вылезло" за границы LinerLayout.

**UPDATE:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Высота серого фона с сердечком соответствует высоте кнопки.

Comment: Ничего непонятно.

Comment: Добавил скриншот для визуальности и сформулирую вопрос так: Как заставить выйти изображение за границы LinerLayout и чтобы оно осталось видимым. Если так нельзя, то каким способом можно.

Comment: чтобы не юзать такую констркукцию используйте у TextView тэг, `drawableLeft="@drawable/i_default_like"` для отступа drawablePadding

Comment: что вообще нужно, чтобы сердечко выходило за рамки парент элемента?

Comment: данное сердечко нет, но эта вся штука находится в ListView и вместо сердечка может быть другая картинка которая должна вылезти за границы парента,